# Laravel 5.4 uploading on cpanel, Laravel Mediable works on local host but have path issue in cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpan

We are using laravel mediable for joining image to model in our web, Code is given below. We have default images in a folder and use Laravel package Intervention for uploading.

```
  protected function create(array $data)
   {
    $user  = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $id = $user->id;

    $uname = $user->name[0];

    $img = Image::make('uploads/users/default/'.$uname.'.png');
    $img->save('uploads/users/images/'.$id.'.png');

    $media = MediaUploader::import('uploads', 'users/images', $id, 'png');
    $user->attachMedia($media, 'user');

    $img = Image::make('uploads/users/default/'.'badge1'.'.png');
    $img->save('uploads/users/images/'.$id.'badge'.'.png');

    $media = MediaUploader::import('uploads', 'users/images', $id.'badge', 'png');
    $user->attachMedia($media, 'badge');
    }
```

But on cpanel path error occurs, Intervention uploads the file on exact location but MediaUploader of Laravel Mediable unable to find file from path to attach it to the user. Can someone help? i hope i have defined the issue correct.